# "router not found" on unit testing PlayFramework Controllers

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm having some trouble trying to unit test my controllers following the [play framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTest#Unit-testing-controllers) steps.

I've created a new app using the java template. Replaced the generated ApplicationTest with the ApplicationTest of the docs, corrected the compile errors related to wrong packages but there still something wrong with the additionalConfigurations that are passed to the FakeApplication `(ImmutableMap.of("play.http.router", "javaguide.tests.Routes"))`
I've tried a lot of different names and directories at `javaguide.tests.Routes`, but i get always the error below.

```
[error] 
[error] 1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Router not found: javaguide.tests.Routes]
[error]   while locating play.api.test.FakeRouterProvider
[error]   while locating play.api.routing.Router
[error] 
[error] 1 error, took 2.931 sec
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
[error]     at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
[error]     at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316)
[error]     at play.api.Application$class.routes(Application.scala:111)
[error]     at play.api.test.FakeApplication.routes(Fakes.scala:197)
[error]     at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:89)
[error]     at play.api.Play.start(Play.scala)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.start(Helpers.java:450)
[error]     at play.test.WithApplication.startPlay(WithApplication.java:44)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Router not found: javaguide.tests.Routes]
[error]     at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
[error]     at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829)
[error]     at play.api.routing.Router$$anonfun$load$2.apply(Router.scala:67)
[error]     at play.api.routing.Router$$anonfun$load$2.apply(Router.scala:66)
[error]     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error]     at play.api.routing.Router$.load(Router.scala:66)
[error]     at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:66)
[error]     at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:63)
[error]     at play.api.test.FakeRouterProvider.get$lzycompute(Fakes.scala:259)
[error]     at play.api.test.FakeRouterProvider.get(Fakes.scala:259)
[error]     at play.api.test.FakeRouterProvider.get(Fakes.scala:258)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
[error]     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
[error]     ... 44 more
[error] Failed: Total 21, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 19, Skipped 1
```

Did anyone knows what I'm missing or can share a reference to a github project that have this kind of tests working?

If it helps, the anatomy of a Play Framework app: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue yesterday, and I have just answered my own question, please see if the answer to this question would help: [Play 2.4: How do I disable routes file loading during unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509026/play-2-4-how-do-i-disable-routes-file-loading-during-unit-tests])

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you have specified your [routes](https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/playframework/playframework/master/documentation/manual/working/javaGuide/main/tests/code/javaguide.tests.routes) file in the package where it needs to be ie. `javaguide.tests`

javaguide.tests.routes:

```
GET  /          controllers.Application.index()
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of different names and directories at javaguide.tests.Routes, but i get always the error above. Considering the app's directory structure, where should I put the javaguide.tests.Routes file?